# JavaScript returns TypeError when I set the arguments as objects

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype, typeerror

I want to test inheritance in JavaScript. I made a sample script but it doesn't work. The program returns TypeError.

```
var Mammal = function(spec) {
    this.name = spec.name;
};

Mammal.prototype.get_name = function() {
    return this.name;
};

var Cat = function(spec) {
    this.name = spec.name;
};  

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();

var cat = new Cat({name: 'Mike'});
console.log(cat.get_name());
```

If I set the arguments of Mammal and Animal functions as non objects, the program runs finely.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace that appears when the TypeError is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
```

The `Mammal` constructor expects an object, with a `name` property. You could do:

```
Cat.prototype = new Mammal({name: null});
```

Or better yet:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
```

Comment: Good answer, just as another option - makin name optional in Mammal constructor: this.name = spec.name || null;. I think it is more elegant than passing null in constructor

Comment: @MarekSadura: But you'd still have to pass an object, `new Mammal({})`, that's not ideal either. Something like `spec = spec || {}; this.name = spec.name || null` might be an option, but doing `new Mammal` to setup inheritance is not great anyway.

Comment: Now, I understand what was the cause of this error. Thanks guys!